How to determine in MS Teams app (based on teams-js.js library) if it runs in a desktop or a mobile
Maybe it can be based on context.app.host.name (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/using-teams-client-library?tabs=javascript%2Cmanifest-teams-toolkit) but it looks like it is more to question teams X outlook and not to question desktop X mobile (enum here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40microsoft/teams-js/hostname?view=msteams-client-js-latest).
Any idea ?

To determine if your Microsoft Teams app is running on a desktop or mobile device using the teams-js library, you can use the teams.getContext() method to retrieve context information about the app. The context object provides various details about the environment in which your app is running. Although teams-js itself does not explicitly indicate whether the app is running on mobile or desktop.
